# PhantomJS get property from an Array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I have an array with scrollHeight and array with images to render video from them.

```
var delayArray = [
    { startDelayPosition: 920 },
    { startDelayPosition: 1640 },
    { startDelayPosition: 2786 },
    { startDelayPosition: 4500 }
     ];
```

Then I use a loop to iterate an array with images and try to check if the current frame enters the range with scrollHeight, I need to multiple duplicate this frame with that scrollHeight directly to emulate situation as user stop scroll the page and watching something(few seconds, for example). But when I try to use elements of this array in the loop - I get from an array its elements as I expected. For example,

```
[{"startDelayPosition":2013}]
```

But If I try to get value from an object, it always equal an undefined.

```
for (let i = 0; i < videoDuration; i += 1) {
let singleValue = page.evaluate((delayArray, scrollStep, i) => {
  return delayArray.filter(v => Math.ceil(v.startDelayPosition / 
      scrollStep) == i);
          }, delayArray, scrollStep, i);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(singleValue[0].startDelayPosition));

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'singleValue[0].startDelayPosition')
```

I guess PhantomJS has some restrictions to access into the structure like this. Or I do something wrong.

Comment: PhantomJS doesn't support arrow functions so the whole `singleValue ` is probably falsey. Be sure to subscribe to `page.onError` callback to catch errors from page context.

Comment: "PhantomJS doesn't support arrow functions" it's very strange, because this code works well `const fourthPoint = page.evaluate((fourthDelayPoint) => {
     return document.querySelector(
      fourthDelayPoint
     ).offsetTop;
    }, fourthDelayPoint);`

Comment: Do you run it with node.js or with native PhantomJS binary? If latter what is its version?

Comment: I run phantomjs throug nodejs. And I use "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.16".

Comment: this bit is executed in node: `page.evaluate((fourthDelayPoint) => {})`, here you can use arrow function, but the code inside of `page.evaluate`, the one that is executed in page context via PhantomJS, must be ES5-compliant.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations